# asp:Menu cursor pointer with Selectable set to false

Tags: css, asp.net

I have an asp:Menu with a couple of levels of MenuItems.  On the sub MenuItem levels, I add Selectable as false:

```
<asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="SubMenu" Value="SubMenu">
```

This causes my mouse cursor to be text.  How can I consistently set it to cursor:pointer for these sub menus?  I've tried the following under the asp:Menu element:

```
<DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="MBLink" />
<StaticHoverStyle CssClass="MBLink" />
```

where the MBLink style is:

```
.MBLink
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

However, this doesn't work consistently and seems to fall back to the text cursor on a post back.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add Css class to the Menu, instead of the memuitem. The following code should work for you.